# Fetch PageLayout from Java using Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, list-metadata

I am trying to fetch an existing Page Layout using the Java client for the Metadata API, in order to update it.

However, I don't think I can properly fetch it, as it is NULL.

Here is my code:

```
    ReadResult readMetadataResult1 = metadataConnection.readMetadata("Layout", new String[] { "bpgdev__test__c-testLayout" });
    ReadResult readMetadataResult2 = metadataConnection.readMetadata("Layout", new String[] { "test__c-testLayout" });

    System.out.println(readMetadataResult1.getRecords().length);//prints 1
    System.out.println(readMetadataResult2.getRecords().length);//prints 1

    Layout layout1 = (Layout)readMetadataResult1.getRecords()[0];//layout1 is NULL
    Layout layout2 = (Layout)readMetadataResult2.getRecords()[0];//layout2 is NULL
```

And my page layout is definitely returned by a listMetadata call. Here is my code for that:

```
    ListMetadataQuery query = new ListMetadataQuery();
    query.setType("Layout");
    FileProperties []fileProperties = metadataConnection.listMetadata(new ListMetadataQuery[]{query}, 42.0);
    for(FileProperties prop: fileProperties){
        System.out.println(prop.getFullName());//outputs test__c-testLayout amongst others
    }
```

Can anyone give me any ideas as to what I am missing?

I have tried both with and without namespace, none working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're having is the Object `Type = "Layout"` (string).

What you want to retrieve is the (string) `fullName = "bpgdev__test__c-testLayout"`.

It's either that or you want to to retrieve the (string) `fullName_type_info`.

I believe it should be one or the other.

Comment: I am sorry I don't think I understand you .. can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: When I look at the MDAPI section for Layout, it shows `String type = 'Layout';`, then there's `String fullname;` and also `String[] fullName_type_info = new String[]{'fullName','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};`. That's what the MDAPI is using to return what you're also looking for. See metadataservice.cls in https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi for more.